# changing class of a tag which is not using id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies for asking more or less the same question again. I just noticed that i am using another name instead of 'id'.

```
<li emage="toto" class="jstree-leaf">
    <ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a class=""><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>Story B</a>
</li>
```

I need to change the class of the `<ins>` tags for a specific `<li>` where emage value is 'toto'.

If i was using 'id' instead of 'emage', i would have used the following:

```
$("#toto ins").attr("class","className");
```

But since am not using id, how can i change the class of the inner `<ins>` tags.

Your suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but just to be clear: The attribute `emage` is not part of standard HTML, and finding elements by this made-up attribute will probably not be as fast as finding them by id, which is *meant* to be used as an index.

Comment: Hi Chuck,thanks for letting me know about this. The thing is that i am already using id to store something else and i need to pass other attributes inside the <li> tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
$('li[emage="toto"] ins').attr('class', 'className');
```

This will update the class of all `ins` tags inside the `li` with the attribute `emage` that has the value "toto"

Answer (score 5):

Use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("li[emage='toto'] ins").attr("class","className");
```